# Chrome Extension for URL Bar pre-load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am looking to develop a Google Chrome extension that affects the way chrome loads text typed into the URL bar.

**Current functionality:** if your text matches history / bookmarks it'll pull those up and auto-populate with the suggestion(s) and if you keep typing it'll update it's suggestions or remove them. If you type something that doesn't match any URL (like "test") it'll just do a search for the word(s) on google.com.

**Goal:** I want to be able to use the extension to listen to the text entered before it sends it to Chrome for loading the site / looking for a search term.
Example: if I type "test" and hit enter, I want the extension to listen to that first, tell Chrome what to do next (load a different site, search for a different word, etc.). Is that possible?

What API's (?) would I use for something like that? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, you need to populate suggestions after hitting enter, is that what you want?

Comment: There's no such API. The closest thing is `chrome.omnibox` but it requires a keyword.